# NLTK - Lemmatizing the tokens before being chunked

Tags: python, nltk

I am currently stuck in this problem.

NLTK's Chunking function is like this:

```
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(word)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
chunking = nltk.chunk.ne_chunk(tagged)
```

is there any way to lemmatize the tokens with its tag before being chunked? Like

`lmtzr.lemmatize('tokens, pos=tagged)`

I have tried to lemmatize the chunk, but it is not working (error says something about chunking being a list). I am new to python, so my knowledge about it isn't that great. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `lemmatize` directly without `pos_tag` -

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

lmtzr = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
word = "Here are words and cars"
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(word)
token_lemma = [ lmtzr.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens ]
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(token_lemma)
chunking = nltk.chunk.ne_chunk(tagged)
```

**Output**

```
['Here', 'are', 'word', 'and', 'car'] # lemmatize output
[('Here', 'RB'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('word', 'NN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('car', 'NN')]
(S Here/RB are/VBP word/NN and/CC car/NN)
```

Comment: Thanks bro! I have a question, will this also solve the problem with the tags? I have read that words ending with -ing is by default lemmatized as a Noun.

Comment: Lemmatization converts words into their root form. It has got nothing to do with POS tagging. Post lemmatization its upto the POS tagger to decide whether the root word will be a noun. Depends on the word and the parser really

Comment: Thanks bro! You were a big help! Cheers!

Comment: do you know how I could take cases where "are" is "'re"?

Comment: `are` and `is` have root word as `be`. so if you lemmatize using `WordNetLemmatizer` you will get `be` - `lmtzr.lemmatize('is', pos="v")` where lmtzr is `lmtzr = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()`